# Why does sudo take a long time if there is a mismatch between /etc/hosts file and the actual hostname?

Tags: debian, sudo, ansible

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343609/sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-hostname-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution

On Debian 12, I changed the hostname using ansible's hostname module. After that, any tasks that require sudo give the error `sudo: unable to resolve host {hostname}: Temporary failure in name resolution`

The linked answer shows how to fix the issue but doesn't really answer why `sudo` works after the error.
Is there a timeout for `sudo` after which it will work? I want to know the mechanism of how it's working.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/429790/

Comment: Why would you expect sudo not to work after this error?

Comment: I just want to understand the behavior of sudo. After looking for the right hosts, and not finding it why does sudo doesn’t stop working. The error seems like it should stop because couldn’t resolve name. Is sudo falling back on something, is there a timeout? That is not answered by superuser link.

Comment: OK, I am just trying to understand why you would expect `sudo` to fail for something like this. I mean, shy should this result in a failure? clearly, `sudo` can run, presumably you have the `%sudo    username=(ALL) ALL` line, so even if it can't sort out the host it is on, it is clever enough to realize that it can execute wherever it is, so it continues. Can you tell us why you would expect it to fail instead? Wouldn't that be a bug?

Comment: I am just trying to understand what's happening behind the scene when there is a mismatch between hostname and hostname in `/etc/hosts`. After the error, why does sudo wait for certain seconds and if there is any file where the timeout period is sete. I wanted to know if it's doing any DNS look up or something as a fall back. I can't seem to find the answer but in Ubuntu there was a file where you can set the timeout.